# "sharepoint" and "sharepy" packages unable to import

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm trying to write a script in python that will modify files and folders in a sharepoint site. Based off what I've read online about working with sharepoint using python, I tried to install and import the "sharepoint" and "sharepy" modules.

I used "pip install sharepoint" and "pip install sharepy" in the command prompt to install the packages, and then in my script used these lines to import the packages:

import sharepoint

import sharepy

Multiple IDE's don't recognize the packages (in Visual Studio, the error says "No module named 'sharepoint'") and I can't use their libraries to complete my code. The modules in question are present in the same subfolder as other modules that do successfully import, so I'm not really understanding the problem here. What could be causing these libraries to not import?

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio code change python path to where you installed python

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a module named "sharepoint"
Instead of that, you have to install : office365-rest-python-client
(with pip)